# How do I take proportions of a value in each column of an array in r?

Tags: arrays, r

I'm trying to simulate a sampling distribution of sample proportions in r from a data set. Here is the code I have so far:

```
library(MASS)
phat=replicate(100, sample (Aids2$status, 50, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL), simplify="matrix")
table(phat)["A"]/50
```

I figured that would divide the number of observations of "A" in each column of the array by fifty so I could get 100 percentages of "A" and I could put those in a histogram, but it just took the total number of observations of "A" in the entire array and divided that by 50 to get something like 39.8 which isn't very useful. I think I got the closest by converting the phat array to a table and then trying to use prop.table on the resulting table, but that didn't work. Here's the code though:

```
newtable = ftable(phat)
prop.table(newtable, margin=NULL)
```

Once again, I only need to get a percentage of "A" in each 50 observation sample to be able to make a histogram, so if anyone has any ideas for this it would be much appreciated.

Comment: Try something like `phat <- replicate(100, sample(Aids2$status, 50), simplify=FALSE)` so that you get 100 lists. Then you can `sapply` or `lapply` your function over the `phat` list.

Comment: I should have said '*a list of 100 vectors*' instead of '*100 lists*'

Comment: In theory, you could fit some function to your data and sample from that function.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but when I tried it I got another error:

Comment: Sorry, that comment was a mistake. The method of using the vectors worked and then I was able to use `phat <- sapply(phat, table)/50` to get a nice even list of A and D percentages, but I can't get rid of the proportions of D to make a histogram of the proportions of A. I tried subsetting the data with the function `newphat <- phat[c("A", 1:100)]` but that just gave me a list of NA. Is there anyway of making a histogram of just one row of the table?

Comment: I figured it out eventually. Here's the final code if you're interested: `library(MASS)
phat=replicate(1000, sample (Aids2$status, 50, replace = FALSE, prob = NULL), simplify=FALSE)
phat <- sapply(phat, table)/50
newphat<-as.list(phat)
finphat <- newphat[ c(T,F) ]
finphat <- as.numeric(finphat)
hist(finphat)` Thanks for your help both of you.